# Can't call to_json on pivoted pandas dataframe: returns "ValueError: Label array sizes do not match corresponding data shape"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database containing time series data from sensors. The graphing library I would like to use on the front end requires that the data be reshaped into one column per sensor instead of the vertical format in my dataset:

```
>>> for d in dataset: print d                                                   
...
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 56, 0, 598000), u'motion', 0.0]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 56, 7, 698000), u'motion', 1.0]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 58, 20, 298000), u'motion', 0.0]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 2, 21, 27, 893000), u'door', 0.0]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 2, 21, 37, 793000), u'door', 1.0]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 2, 21, 53, 893000), u'door', 0.0]
```

With some help from stackoverflow and the pandas documentation (thanks!) I figured out how to pivot the data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['tstamp', 'tag', 'value'])              
>>> dfp = df.pivot('tstamp', 'tag')
>>> dfp
                                 value
tag                         door  motion
tstamp
2014-09-26 00:56:00.598000         NaN            0
2014-09-26 00:56:07.698000         NaN            1
2014-09-26 00:58:20.298000         NaN            0
2014-09-26 02:21:27.893000           0          NaN
2014-09-26 02:21:37.793000           1          NaN
2014-09-26 02:21:53.893000           0          NaN
>>>
```

Now I'm stuck trying to output the data in JSON:

```
>>> dfp.to_json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/environment/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 853, in to_json
    default_handler=default_handler)
  File "/var/www/environment/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 34, in to_json
    date_unit=date_unit, default_handler=default_handler).write()
  File "/var/www/environment/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 77, in write
    default_handler=self.default_handler)
ValueError: Label array sizes do not match corresponding data shape
```

I am new to pandas so I am guessing that I need to fix my "label arrays". What do I do? I can see that

```
>>> dfp.keys()
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'value'], [u'door', u'motion']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=[None, u'tag'])
```

But I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pivot` is making a DataFrame whose columns have a MultiIndex. Since the top level, `value`, is the same for all columns, you could simply drop it:

```
dfp.columns = dfp.columns.droplevel(0)
```

and then calling `to_json` works:

```
In [20]: dfp.to_json()
Out[20]: '{"door":{"1411692960598":null,"1411692967698":null,"1411693100298":null,"1411698087893":0.0,"1411698097793":1.0,"1411698113893":0.0},"motion":{"1411692960598":0.0,"1411692967698":1.0,"1411693100298":0.0,"1411698087893":null,"1411698097793":null,"1411698113893":null}}'
```

---

Or, better yet, specify the `values` column when calling `pivot`:

```
In [26]: dfp = df.pivot(index='tstamp', columns='tag', values='value'); dfp
Out[26]: 
tag                         door  motion
tstamp                                  
2014-09-26 00:56:00.598000   NaN       0
2014-09-26 00:56:07.698000   NaN       1
2014-09-26 00:58:20.298000   NaN       0
2014-09-26 02:21:27.893000     0     NaN
2014-09-26 02:21:37.793000     1     NaN
2014-09-26 02:21:53.893000     0     NaN
```

and now calling `to_json` works out-of-the-box, since the columns index is flat.

Comment: That works! I found that to keep the desired `tstamp` orientation I could use `dfp.to_json(orient='index')`. I wonder if there isn't a way to use to_json directly instead of pivot?

Comment: Thanks for your additional suggestion. Even better.

Comment: The pivot changes column values into column labels. None of the `orient` options (split, records, index, columns, values) does that, so no I think you need to call pivot.